# Sub domain redirection to taxonomy

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomains

Hi all I want to use sub domain for my taxonomy like that :

http://taxonomy.domain.com/apple map to http://www.domain.com/taxonomy/apple

I add this to my vhost

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^taxonomy\.domain\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$        http://www.domain.com/taxonomy/$1 [L]
```

And add a wildcard to my dns configuration.

The redirection works but I want to use only rewrite but not redirection. So I want to use the target page but still have the subdomain url.

So taxonomy.domain.com/apple is map but not redirect to the taxonomy url

Any help?

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't thin you can when you are changing domains. You are moving people from taxonomy. to www. If this was possible then I could rewrite cake.something.net to paypal.com for example

Comment: This is possible. You can actually do anything you wish with rewrites. @BarryCarlyon You can rewrite a custom URL to paypal.com using proxypass or a simple htaccess rewrite. The site won't function properly, but it will display, though not advisable.

Comment: I think this is a question that should be asked in stack overflow as this relates more to Apache than WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the line `Options +FollowSymlinks` defined in the .htaccess file before your rewrite rules?

If so, remove it. If not, add it.